# Lookup a number in a collection of ranges in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

As in the example below, I have a table containing a collection of ranges.

Each range has an associated description.  I want to look up the description for a number that falls within one of the ranges, but is not explicitly listed as a range endpoint.

**For example**: Find the description associated with the value `208` in the table below.

```
--------------------------------------
| Item | Location Description        |
|------------------------------------|  
| 1    | 100 to 103 agenda           |
| 2    | 106 to 111 Notes of Meeting |  
| 3    | 112 to 123 revision         |
| 4    | 200 to 210 factor           |
--------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What if the value is a) <100; b) 104 or 105; c) 124-199; d) >210?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this is what you're looking for.  If you create a table in a slightly different format, you can use a built-in Excel function to do this as a simple lookup:

[image: screenshot]

Instead of showing the ranges in the form in your question, use a table that has the starting value for each range.  I added values to fill in the gaps where you have breaks, and assigned the description as "error" in case someone tries to use an undefined number.

In column C, I entered some numbers to show how values will work relative to the ranges.  The formula for the result is in column D.  In D1:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,A$1:B$7,2,1)
```

This looks up the value from column C in the first column of the table, looking for the highest value that does not exceed the lookup value.  It takes the result from the second column of the table.  The last `1` parameter indicates that the values are in ascending order.

Comment: you got my concern, but the table already done by other person and it is so large file to re-work, is there any way rather than doing it again or just replace "to" of any math character that represent value in between. in result of when you search it , value will show?

Comment: The "to" is irrelevant.  Whatever is between the numbers is just to make it easier for people to read.  To use a range in a cell, you need to extract the numbers.  I posted another answer that attacks the problem that way.

Answer (score 1):

#### The approach

OK, based on your comment, a totally different approach that doesn't involve rebuilding the data.  This approach uses a couple of helper columns to do the heavy lifting on your data.  These can be hidden, although I'll leave them showing in the example so you can see how this works.

This example is based on an assumption that all of the ranges involve three-digit numbers.  If not, we would need to parse the range endpoints another way, like locating one of the spaces in the range phrase and then calculating where the range values are.

[image: screenshot]

I picked B7 to enter the lookup value, and C7 to display the lookup result.  The helper columns are E and F.

#### How it works

In column E, we look to see if the target value is in that row's range.  If it is, that row's description is displayed.  Otherwise the cell is left blank.  So in column E, only the row in which the target is found will show the description.

Column F successively concatenates the column E results.  Since this joins blanks for the non-matching ranges to whatever description is displayed, the last cell in Column F will display the description from wherever it appears.  C7 just displays the last cell in column F.

#### The formulas

My data starts in row 2, so E2 contains:

```
=IF(AND(B$7>=--LEFT(B2,3),B$7<=--RIGHT(B2,3)),C2,"")
```

Copy that down the row as needed.  The AND compares the target value (B7) to both ends of the row's range.  It uses the LEFT and RIGHT functions to extract the three digits from each end of the string.  The double negatives force Excel to treat these numeric strings as actual numbers.  The empty double quotes at the end are a null value that will leave the cell blank if the test is false (the quotes should have nothing between them).

F2 contains:

=F1&E2

Copy that down the row as needed.  Note that this relies on F1 being empty.  This takes whatever is in the cell above and concatenates whatever is the result in Column E for the row.

The result cell, C7 contains:

=F5

In this example, F5 is the result in the last data row.

As mentioned earlier, columns E and F can be hidden, so I showed the action in two columns to make it easier to visualize.  However, E and F can be combined, and the action accomplished with one helper column.  For example, make F the helper column and replace the reference to the column E cell with the column E formula.  So leave out column E, and F2 would be:

```
=F1&IF(AND(B$7>=--LEFT(B2,3),B$7<=--RIGHT(B2,3)),C2,"")
```

#### Note

With this solution, if a target number is entered that is not covered by one of the defined ranges, it won't be found on any data row, so the result will be blank.